# While sharing a vcf file in iOS , the file is not getting attached in mail using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, cncontact, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to share a vcf file using UIActivityViewController. It shares the file with all other options except mail. It just opens the mail composer without any attachment. Here's my code:

```
guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return
        }


        var filename = NSUUID().uuidString



        if let fullname = CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact) {
            filename = fullname.components(separatedBy: " ").joined(separator: " ")
        }

        let fileURL = directoryURL
        .appendingPathComponent(filename)
        .appendingPathExtension("vcf")

        do{
            let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])

            print("filename: \(filename)")
            print("contact: \(String(describing: String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)))")

            try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [.atomicWrite])
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [fileURL],
        applicationActivities: nil
        )

        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**I want to attach this contact as a vcf file in mail app when user selects mail option for sharing.**

Comment: Can you share a demo project of what you are required to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use mimeType **@"text/x-vcard"** for a vcf file in addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName of MFMailComposeViewController

Here is draft code using your's i have tested.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        var contacts = [CNContact]()
        let keys = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactVCardSerialization.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)

        do {
            try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) {
                (contact, stop) in
                // Array containing all unified contacts from everywhere
                contacts.append(contact)
            }
            self.shareContact(contact: contacts.first!)

        }
        catch {
            print("unable to fetch contacts")
        }


}


    func shareContact(contact:CNContact) {

        guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return
        }

        var filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        if let fullname = CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact) {
                 filename = fullname.components(separatedBy: " ").joined(separator: " ")
             }

             let fileURL = directoryURL
             .appendingPathComponent(filename)
             .appendingPathExtension("vcf")

             do{
                 let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])

                 print("filename: \(filename)")
                 print("contact: \(String(describing: String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)))")

                print(fileURL)
                try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [.atomicWrite])
             }
             catch{
                 print(error.localizedDescription)
             }

            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { (t) in

            self.showActivityController(fileURL: fileURL)
            t.invalidate()
        }

    }
    func showActivityController (fileURL:URL) {


        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [fileURL],
        applicationActivities: nil
        )

        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you check my code? I'm using UIActivityViewController not a MFMailComposeViewController. I want more than one option for my file to share including mail, so I just can't use MFMailComposeViewController alone.

Comment: which ios you are using for testing i just tried your code and it's attaching vcf card to email successfully.

Comment: I'm testing on iOS version 13.1

Comment: i have updated my answer based on the implementation i am also using 13.3 for testing.

Comment: timer was used just to avoid presentation error so you can ignore that.

Comment: Ok, first of all, I'm not using CNContactStore instead I'm using CNContactPickerViewController to fetch the particular CNContact. & second, I'm not seeing any difference in your "shareContact" code & mine.

Comment: yes contact picker should n't matter strange is that in your mail it's not getting attached do you have another device to try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205217/discussion-between-suhail-and-muhammad-afzal).

Comment: @Suhail I'm also facing the same issue as yours. .vcf file not getting attached when I share it via Gmail but works on other options. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal I'm also facing the same issue as yours. .vcf file not getting attached when I share it via Gmail using actionsheetcontroller but works on other options. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @ParthBarot You just need to update your device. That worked for me. Look for any software updates that are pending.

Comment: @Suhail I have updated to the latest iOS 14 but still not working. Which version do you have for this working?

Comment: @ParthBarot Did you delete previous build & installed the new one?

Comment: @Suhail Yes I installed new build then checked but not fixed. In your device in which version working can you please tell ?

Comment: I was using 13.1 version then I upgraded to 13.2.

Comment: Having the same issue in iOS 14.5.. Did anyone found a solution?

Comment: @ParthBarot any solution you got?

Comment: @ParthBarot try to update OS version.

Comment: @Suhail it's already updated os version